# Android List NullPointerException

Tags: android, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I have this piece of code and it's causing NullPointerException

```
private List<Player> playerList;
private List<String> playerName;

Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
this.currentGame = b.getParcelable("created_tournament");
playerList = currentGame.getPlayers();
for (int i = 0; i < playerList.size(); i ++) {
    this.playerName.add(this.playerList.get(i).getName());
    Log.d(TAG, "Input was not a number!" + this.playerList.get(i).getName());
}
```

with playerList is `List<Player>` taken from a Parcelable object and `playerName` is `List<String>`.

Theoretically, `this.playerName.add(this.playerList.get(i).getName());` should works since `Log.d(TAG, "Input was not a number!" + this.playerList.get(i).getName());` works fine without causing any exception

Any idea?

Comment: It's always a good idea to point out which line is causing the exception when asking for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `playerName` list in not initialized, and you call the method `add` on it while it's `null`.

Change that:

```
private List<String> playerName;
```

to :

```
private List<String> playerName = new ArrayList<String>();
```